# Edit the contents of an enclosed wordpress shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I've written a shortcode that works great for all the attributes. 
However, I want the shortcode to allow me to adjust the contents of lists within the `shortcode`. 
This is because I need to markup for rich snippets and currently do it in HTML but this is lost when I switch back to the visual editor.

Below is an example of what I would like to do. Is this possible? Or is there an example somewhere to use for this? All the `shortcode examples` I can find are very simple.

Input

```
[ReviewMg title="Test title" image="test.jpg"]
 [ul]
  [li]Point 1[/li]
  [li]Point 2[/li]
  [li]Point 3[/li]
 [/ul]
[/reviewMg]
```

Output

```
<h3>Key Points</h3>
<ul>
 <li itemprop="keyInfo">Point 1</li>
 <li itemprop="keyInfo">Point 2</li>
 <li itemprop="keyInfo">Point 3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a trivial example of an enclosing shortcode:

```
function caption_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
    return '<span class="caption">' . $content . '</span>';
}
add_shortcode( 'caption', 'caption_shortcode' );
```

Since $content is included in the return value without any escaping or encoding, the user can include raw HTML:

```
[caption]<a href="http://example.com/">My Caption</a>[/caption]
```

Which would produce:

```
<span class="caption"><a href="http://example.com/">My Caption</a></span>
```

for more info check https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Enclosing_vs_self-closing_shortcodes

you can also check plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/nested-shortcodes/